# How to hide code from editor using a projection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I am working on a custom language service. Code files of the language contain both metadata and source code, whereby metadata is stored as a header (at the beginning of the file; this requirement can´t be changed). The language service provides two logical views; one for the code and another one allowing to edit the metadata.

Now, the problem is that I want to hide the metadata from the code editor view - and I thought implementing it using projection is the way to go, but the Visual Studio SDK does neither contain any examples nor a good explanation on how to implement such functionality. Just a short explanation about the concept is given at: [Inside the Editor, Projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx#projection)

I also found a language service project at Codeplex: [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://pytools.codeplex.com/), which has Django support (in this project projection buffers are used to mix HTML markup and Python code), but this seems to be a different scenario...

This is what I tried...

Within my editor factory, I create an `IVsTextLines` instance that is used by the code editor view using the following code...

```
private IVsTextLines GetTextBuffer(IntPtr docDataExisting)
{
    if (docDataExisting == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Type t = typeof(IVsTextLines);
        Guid clsId = typeof(VsTextBufferClass).GUID;
        Guid interfaceId = t.GUID;

        IVsTextLines bufferInstance;
        if ((bufferInstance = this.Package.CreateInstance(ref clsId, ref interfaceId, t) as IVsTextLines) != null)
        {
            object oleServiceProvider = this.GetService(typeof(IServiceProvider));
            var withSite = (IObjectWithSite)bufferInstance;
            withSite.SetSite(oleServiceProvider);
            return bufferInstance;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

From what I´ve seen so far is that the `IVsTextLines` interface is not compatible with `IProjectionBuffer`, `ITextBuffer` and so on. I learned from the Python Tools project that I can use a `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService` to get an `ITextBuffer` instance from the `IVsTextLines` object; the adapter factory service (as well as some other required service instances) gets injected into my editor factory via MEF...

```
IVsTextBuffer textBuffer = this.GetTextBuffer(...);
ITextBuffer documentBuffer = this.editorAdaptersFactoryService.GetDocumentBuffer(textBuffer);
```

The `ITextBuffer` can be used as a source buffer for projections... my idea is to create an elision buffer having to spans; one for the metadata and one for the code, whereby the metadata span will be elided which makes the code disapear, and use this elision buffer as the projection. This is what I tried...

```
private ITextBuffer CreateBuffer(
    IProjectionEditResolver editResolver, 
    ITextBuffer documentBuffer)
{
    IContentType contentType = this.ContentTypeRegistryService.GetContentType("...");

    ITextSnapshot currentSnapshot = documentBuffer.CurrentSnapshot;

    string text = currentSnapshot.GetText(0, currentSnapshot.Length);
    TextRange textRange = Parser.GetMetadataTextRange(text); // parse code; return a text range representing the code to elide

    ITrackingSpan elideSpan = currentSnapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(textRange.Start, textRange.Length, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeExclusive);

    int offset = textRange.Start + textRange.Length;
    ITrackingSpan expandSpan = currentSnapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(offset, currentSnapshot.Length - offset, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);

    SnapshotSpan elide = elideSpan.GetSpan(currentSnapshot);
    SnapshotSpan expand = expandSpan.GetSpan(currentSnapshot);

    var snapshotSpans = new List<SnapshotSpan>
       {
           elide, 
           expand
       };

    var spanCollection = new NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection(snapshotSpans);

    const ElisionBufferOptions BufferOptions = ElisionBufferOptions.FillInMappingMode;
    IElisionBuffer buffer = this.ProjectionBufferFactoryService.CreateElisionBuffer(editResolver, spanCollection, BufferOptions, contentType);
    buffer.ModifySpans(new NormalizedSpanCollection(elide), new NormalizedSpanCollection(expand));  

    return buffer;
}
```

Once the elision buffer is created, I use the `SetDataBuffer` method to connect it with the editor...

```
ITextBuffer buffer = this.CreateBuffer(..., documentBuffer);
this.editorAdaptersFactory.SetDataBuffer(textBuffer, buffer);
```

This works somehome; at least the metadata code disapears from the code editor, but as soon as try to edit the code, I got an `InvalidOperationException`, which is not the case, if I create the elision buffer with just a single span, or if I don´t hide the `elideSpan`.

The following error is reported to the `ActivityLog`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Shim buffer length mismatch. Document=11594 Surface=11577 Difference at 0&#x000D;&#x000A;   at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextBufferAdapter.OnTextBufferChanged(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)
```

I think I am quite close to the final solution; so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I stumbled across this while Googling for a similar problem with Elision Buffers. I think Slaks is doing something similar with ProjectionBuffers in WebEssentials. https://github.com/SLaks/WebEssentials2013/tree/master/EditorExtensions/Classifications/Markdown

Specifically, look at CodeLanguageEmbedder.cs (It has a GlobalPrefix for CSharp). Also look at ContainedLanguageAdapter.cs. He uses LanguageProjection, but it's similar to regular ProjectionBuffers.

Comment: Also, it might just be a typo on the question, but your elideSpans is set to "snapshotSpan" not "snapshotSpan1".

Comment: @JoshVarty I updated the code in the question. I think you have some experience regarding elision- and/or projection-buffers (you´ve also asked a question about it); I would be glad, if you could help me to fix it...

Comment: I'm not super experienced unfortunately, but I can try. Are you intentionally returning `buffer` as opposed to `projectionBuffer`? I see you make the projectionBuffer, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: My problem is that there´s no explanation on MSDN on how to use all this correctly. The code in the question shows what I´ve tried so far (there is some text in the beginning of the file and I just want to hide it). The problem remains either I use the `ElisionBuffer` or `ProjectionBuffer`...

Comment: So that exception is being thrown because some internal state is being messed up -- the "surface buffer" and "document buffer" should be the same size after an edit but they're not. This has nothing to do with which spans are and aren't being included in the elision buffer. As long as you're eliding something with this technique of buffer creation you'll have an issue.

Comment: So looking at the code, it's presuming data buffer = document buffer, at least by logical contents. So you'll have to construct your buffer differently and honestly, I don't know how to do that without asking the editor team directly. :-(